# How do you write multiple lines of replaceable console output in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to have three different lines of text in the terminal display the different count progresses. The problem is they overwrite each other and honestly I don't know what to do anymore.  Any tips or fixes?

```
def first():
    for i in range(50,0,-1):
        sys.stdout.write("\rThe current chicken is: {:<3d}".format(i))
        time.sleep(1)
    
def second():
    for i in range(100,0,-1):
        sys.stdout.write("\rThe current number is: {:<3d}".format(i))
        time.sleep(1)

def third():
    for i in range(1000,0,-1):
        sys.stdout.write("\rThe current cow is: {:<3d}".format(i))
        time.sleep(1)

awidj = [first, second, third]

for thread in awidj:
    threading.Thread(target=thread).start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\r` will just overwrite the last line that was written. Since you have multiple threads here, there is no way to control which one that is.

For more precise control over console output, check out [the `curses` module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

Comment: This curses thing is quite confusing, do you have an example that could help me understand it?

Comment: @Lugaw Yes, curses is complex. You can google "python curses example" to find examples.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting curses. Took me quite a while to figure out but it eventually worked. Thanks again.